# how to check whether cell has anything in it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with 6 columns, the first 3 rows are reserved for heading. Once the user enters information in 5 cells of the row he would execute a script that would send an email. The 6th cell is for showing EMAIL_SENT after the email was sent.

What i have problem with is error checking, i dont want the user to send an email without all five cells having data in it.

```
function Email() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getDataRange();
range = range.offset(3, 0, range.getNumRows()-3);

range.getValues().forEach( function( recipient, index, data ){

        if (recepient[0] == ""){Browser.msgBox("No data in column A");}
        .
        .         
        .    
});
}
```

I was hoping i could check if the cell is equal to nothing, blank and notify but this is not working.

Your help is much appreciated.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you are using works but is not able to call the Browser service...

If you replace with a `Logger.log` you get the result as expected.

```
  range.getValues().forEach( function( recipient, index, data ){
    if (recipient[0] == ""){Logger.log("Missing data in column A");}
  });
```

IMHO, it is after all far more convenient than getting many popups appearing in my UI...

---

### EDIT:

below is a code that will show a warning when no data is present in col A

```
  range = range.offset(3, 0, range.getNumRows()-3);
  var result=false;
  range.getValues().forEach( function( recipient, index, data ){
    if (recipient[0] == ""){result="Missing data in column A"}
  });
  if(result){Browser.msgBox(result);  return };
```

Comment: Thanks Serge...... Would there be another way to notify the user that one or more of the cell values are missing but still using range.getValues().forEach( function(recipient, index, data) ?

Comment: short answer is yes.. I'll edit with a suggestion ;-)

Comment: This works great, thank you.... One last question, how could i break the process if one of the cells are empty.

Comment: what do you mean ? which process do you want to stop ? when the browser popup shows up the process is already finished...

Comment: Right now the script sends the email even if one or more of the cells are  missing. What i'd like is, once the user acknowledges the msgbox notifying about the missing data the script would just stop without sending an incomplete email.

Comment: ok, simply add `return;` right after the `Browse.msgBox()` command

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried *isBlank()* in the Range class?

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#isBlank()