# How to check if a cell is empty before copying to a new sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to copy a row of data to a new sheet, but only if the date the data was entered is before today AND if either of two cells in the row contain information. 
My code currently works by checking a cell the date was entered for dates before today, and successfully copies the row to a new sheet, and deletes it from the row it was on. I am currently having trouble adding in the code to additionally check if either of two other cells are blank. If both cells are blank, I want the code to skip that row and continue to the next one, and will check the date of that row, and the two cells, etc. If either cell contains data AND if the date is before today, I want the code to copy the whole row to another sheet. FYI, my data starts in row 5 on my spreadsheet.

```
    function DailyTransfer() {
    var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Daily Overview");
      var CopyTo =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("2019 YTD");
      var ColumntoSearch = 2;
      var ColumntoSearch2 = 21;
      var ColumntoSearch3 = 25;
      var LastRow = Sheet.getLastRow();

    //Gets column to search for dates to compare to Today
      var Range = Sheet.getRange(5, ColumntoSearch, LastRow, 1);
      var Values = Range.getValues();

    //Sets the amount of data to copy over
      var NumberofColumns = 27;
      var NumberofRows = 1;
      var DestRow = CopyTo.getLastRow()+1;

    //Compares all the dates the information was entered in the Daily Overview tab to Today
      var dt=new Date();
      var dv=new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()).valueOf();
      var d=0;

      for(var i=0;i<Values.length;i++) {
        var Check1 = Sheet.getRange(i-d+5, ColumntoSearch2).getCell; //check first cell
        var Check2 = Sheet.getRange(i-d+5, ColumntoSearch3).getCell; //check second cell
        if(Approved.isBlank()){ //If Check1 is blank, go Check2
         if (Denied.isBlank()){
            i+1}} //If Check1 and Check2 are blank, go to next row
    //If either of Check1 or Check2 contains data, copy that row of data to a new sheet. 
//If both Check1 and Check2 are blank, the row is skipped and the next row is
// checked. This is the part I'm having trouble on. I think I need to close my
// loop here, or create a loop within a loop?
        else {
          if(new Date(Values[i][0]).valueOf()<dv){
          var RangetoCopy=Sheet.getRange(i-d+5,1,NumberofRows,NumberofColumns); 
          var DestRange=CopyTo.getRange(CopyTo.getLastRow()+1,1,NumberofRows,NumberofColumns);
          RangetoCopy.copyTo(DestRange);
          Sheet.deleteRows(i-d+5);
            d++;}}}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to check whether cell has anything in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26847889/how-to-check-whether-cell-has-anything-in-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function DailyTransfer() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("Daily Overview");
  var dsh=ss.getSheetByName("2019 YTD");  
  var rg1=sh.getRange(5,2,sh.getLastRow()-4, 1);
  var rg2=sh.getRange(5,21,sh.getLastRow()-4,1);
  var rg3=sh.getRange(5,25,sh.getLastRow()-4,1);
  var vA1=rg1.getValues();
  var vA2=rg2.getValues();
  var vA3=rg3.getValues()
  var dt=new Date();
  var dv=new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()).valueOf();
  var d=0;
  for(var i=0;i<vA1.length;i++) {
    if((new Date(vA1[i][0]).valueOf()<dv) && (vA2[i][0] || vA3[i][0])) {
      var RangetoCopy=sh.getRange(i-d+5,1,1,27); 
      var DestRange=dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow()+1,1,1,27);
      RangetoCopy.copyTo(DestRange);
      sh.deleteRow(i-d+5);
      d++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I just tried this, and it appears that nothing happened. I have 5 rows of data, and two should have been copied over to the new sheet and deleted, because one of the rows contains a value in the vA2 range, and one contains a value in the vA3 range, and both rows are from before today. Not sure why this did not work?

Comment: If you can share some of your data be glad to test it

Comment: I just changed this `new Date(vA1[i][0]).valueOf()>dv` to this `new Date(vA1[i][0]).valueOf()<dv` and I try to test it a bit better.  It's always great if you could provide some of your data so that we can use it for testing purposes.

Comment: @Elise I put together some of my quick data and it looks like it's working.  I think that greater than to less than was the issue.  Sorry about that.

Comment: I also noticed that `deleteRows()` is depredated so I replaced with `deleteRow()`

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice the ">" was flipped the wrong way. I just changed it to "<" and it worked great. Thanks!